# Refresh data (pivot table) of external link source without opening it (from 2nd file)

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**

I have two files (let's call them Book1 and Book2) which are linked to each other (with index MATCH MATCH formulas; therefore an external link).

Book1: Has a list of items (eg Apple, Banana, Orange) and quantities for each item in one sheet (Sheet1) which are then summarized in a pivot table in Sheet 2.

Book2: Is a summary list and basically looks up the quantities from Book1 with an Index match match (which works perfectly).

The raw data is dumped (with the use of Alteryx) in Book1 (Sheet1).

**Problem**
Is there a way for me to refresh the data in the pivot table (Book1.Sheet2) without opening the file but when opening Book2?

**Trial**
This is the code I have found through my research which seems to work for others but not for me:

```
Public Sub refreshXLS()
    Path = "C:\Users\cae0030\Documents\Book1.xlsx"  'the workbook path you want to refresh
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With

    Workbooks.Open Path
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    PivotTable.RefreshTable
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Basically when I open Book2, nothing happens. When I open VBA and try to run it manually, it gives me a '424' Object required error for `PivotTable.RefreshTable`. It does not give me the error when I just open Book2 but also does not refresh anything.

*Does anyone know what is wrong with my code or has any idea how I could make it work (with a different code)?*

Thank you!

Comment: Excel doesn't know what `PivotTable` is. You need to reference the specific pivot table. See the [`PivotTable.RefreshTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.refreshtable) documentation for an example.

Comment: Yeah try `Dim pT As PivotTable`;`Set pT = Sheets("SheetPivotOn").PivotTables("PivotTableName")`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I added `Set pT = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1")` and then `pT.RefreshTable` and it works when I manually go into VBA & click run but not when I open the file? Do I need to add a `Workbook_Open() ` code first?

Comment: I found the solution (I will also add it to my original post). I added a `Auto_Open()` code in a new module in Book2 to run the code automatically when the file opens and it seems to work. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the input from the comments (and the link from BigBen) I was able to make the following code work perfectly for my case:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Dim pT As PivotTable 'to define PivotTable

    Path = "C:\Users\cae0030\Documents\Book1.xlsx"  'the workbook path you want to refresh

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With

    Workbooks.Open Path
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Set pT = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1") 'to set pT to desired pivot table 
    pT.RefreshTable
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Hint: I added the code to a *Module* with the Sub `Auto_Open()` so it would automatically run when the file is opening.